# Как сбросить привязку Tomcat к другому проекту?

Tags: tomcat

Извините за столь детский вопрос.

Какое-то время назад я пытался собрать проект с применением `Tomcat`. Тогда проект пришлось оставить и переключиться на другой. `Tomcat` остался, СУБД осталась. Сейчас запустил `Tomcat` с терминала — работает! Но почему-то отображает страницу, которая была собрана тогда, при первых попытках. Сейчас я создал новый проект в `IntelliJ IDEA`, подключил `Tomcat`. Сервер запустился без проблем:

```
/Users/promoscow/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/bin/catalina.sh run
[2017-06-19 08:52:24,278] Artifact CrudJavaRushTest: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
19-Jun-2017 20:52:30.359 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
19-Jun-2017 20:52:30.361 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jan 10 2017 21:02:52 UTC
19-Jun-2017 20:52:30.361 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.11.0
19-Jun-2017 20:52:30.361 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Mac OS X
19-Jun-2017 20:52:30.361 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.12.5
19-Jun-2017 20:52:30.362 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          x86_64
19-Jun-2017 20:52:30.362 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
19-Jun-2017 20:52:30.362 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_92-b14
19-Jun-2017 20:52:30.362 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
19-Jun-2017 20:52:30.362 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /Users/promoscow/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea15/tomcat/Unnamed_CrudJavaRushTest
19-Jun-2017 20:52:30.362 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /Users/promoscow/apache-tomcat-8.5.11
19-Jun-2017 20:52:30.363 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/Users/promoscow/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea15/tomcat/Unnamed_CrudJavaRushTest/conf/logging.properties
19-Jun-2017 20:52:30.365 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
19-Jun-2017 20:52:30.366 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
19-Jun-2017 20:52:30.366 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
19-Jun-2017 20:52:30.366 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
19-Jun-2017 20:52:30.366 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
19-Jun-2017 20:52:30.366 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
19-Jun-2017 20:52:30.366 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
19-Jun-2017 20:52:30.366 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
19-Jun-2017 20:52:30.366 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Users/promoscow/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea15/tomcat/Unnamed_CrudJavaRushTest
19-Jun-2017 20:52:30.366 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/Users/promoscow/apache-tomcat-8.5.11
19-Jun-2017 20:52:30.367 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/Users/promoscow/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/temp
19-Jun-2017 20:52:30.367 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/promoscow/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
19-Jun-2017 20:52:30.615 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
19-Jun-2017 20:52:30.650 SEVERE [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
 java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:972)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:237)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:558)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:968)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)

19-Jun-2017 20:52:30.652 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:494)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:970)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:972)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:237)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:558)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:968)
    ... 13 more

19-Jun-2017 20:52:30.653 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-62169"]
19-Jun-2017 20:52:30.662 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
19-Jun-2017 20:52:30.664 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 704 ms
19-Jun-2017 20:52:30.697 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
19-Jun-2017 20:52:30.697 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
19-Jun-2017 20:52:30.707 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-62169]
19-Jun-2017 20:52:30.712 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 48 ms
Connected to server
[2017-06-19 08:52:31,095] Artifact CrudJavaRushTest: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[2017-06-19 08:52:31,623] Artifact CrudJavaRushTest: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2017-06-19 08:52:31,624] Artifact CrudJavaRushTest: Deploy took 528 milliseconds
19-Jun-2017 20:52:40.711 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /Users/promoscow/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/webapps/manager
19-Jun-2017 20:52:40.781 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /Users/promoscow/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/webapps/manager has finished in 69 ms
```

Но страница загружается старая! Подскажите, что в этой ситуации следует сделать, чтобы `Tomcat` отображал новый проект.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас уже запущен процесс который слушает на этом же порту. Поэтому второй запустить нельзя.

Вам надо остановить тот процесс, который вы запустили до этого. Посмотрите в IDEA вкладку **Run**.

Или запустите **Activity Monitor** и найдите в нем запущенный процесс. Ищите процесс **java** в дополнительной информации о процессе в разделе **Open files and ports** первой строчкой будет что-то вроде `/Users/promoscow/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/bin`